# Win form DataGridView dynamically adding button column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'd like to add a button column dynamically to a DataGridView after it has been populated. 
The button column is visible after adding it, but when I try to loop through the DataGridView rows, I get a null for the button in each cell.

```
var buttonCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
buttonCol.Name = "ButtonColumnName";
buttonCol.HeaderText = "Header";
buttonCol.Text = "Button Text";

dataGridView.Columns.Add(buttonCol);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    var button = (Button)row.Cells["ButtonColumnName"].Value;
    // button is null here!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the exact same thing a while ago and couldn't get it working; my solution (as it was just a test application) was to change the background colour of the button cell and test for that. Pretty awful. However, looking back at the code - have you tried casting the `row.Cells["ButtonColumnName"]` to a `DataGridViewButtonCell` and then checking out the properties on that?

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows) 
{ 
    // DataGridViewButtonCell button = (row.Cells["ButtonColumnName"] as DataGridViewButtonCell); 
    row.Cells["ButtonColumnName"].Value = "ButtonText";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the bellow code in your code, then you can see "Button Text" on each boutton:

```
buttonCol.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find this MSDN article useful: [How to: Disable Buttons in a Button Column in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewButtonCell button = (row.Cells["ButtonColumnName"] as DataGridViewButtonCell);        
}
```